# Eclipse plugin not using proxy (407 authentication required)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin and recently I found a bug which is getting painful since I'm not finding a proper solution - my eclipse plugin is made so that it has to get some information from an site from external web. The problem is that when using proxy (with username and password - and ONLY when authentication is required), my plugin is not taking into consideration the user and the pass for the proxy and I get 407 Authentication Required as a response to each HttpRequest executed (for e.g. a corporate proxy that has to be added in order to get to the external web)
If for example I'm trying to use a proxy without user and password, everything is working fine.

My question is - does anyone encounter this before? Do I have to somehow pass the host, port, user, pass to the HttpClient from the IDE? If not, why does it work without authentication and not working with it?

Any ideas would be very helpful!
Thanks alot! :)

I tested to see if the connection is getting through the proxy and it is (of course without the user and pass). I noticed the calls in the logs of the proxy server.

Some additional info would be that the connectivity to that specific website is made through a service layer that is imported as a maven dependency in the project (also written by me). The funny part is that I use the exact same service layer for the Eclipse plugin, but also for an Intellij plugin and in the Intellij one, everything is working properly and I don't get the 407 Authentication Required. (the calls are made exactly the same because they both use the same service layer).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have to use `IProxyService` to get the Eclipse proxy info (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3160435/2670892)) - are you doing that?

Comment: @greg-449 I saw that I can take those settings with IProxyServer, but firstly I tried to set them manually on the HttpClient, just for testing purposes and it just doesn't work